# how to save loop result in multiple csv r

Tags: r, loops, csv, output

I read multiple csv files and get a list of 11 data frames. Now I want to use each data frame in the list to get a new table and save it to a csv file with the origin name separately.

I read csv file by

```
path <- "D:/DATA/01/processdata/singlecity"
fileNames = list.files(path, pattern="*.csv$")
filePath <- sapply(fileNames, function(x){ 
paste(path,x,sep='/')}) 
dfs <- lapply(filePath, function(x){
read.csv(x, header=T)})
```

then get a list of dataframe like :

```
EU CHINA USA
```

```
for (i in data){
   y <- data.table(i)
   y <- dplyr::filter(y, grepl('2002|2003|2004|2005|2006', V2))
   write.csv(y, "y.csv')
}
```

what I want to output is that:

```
EU_t1.csv
CHINA_t2.csv
USA_t3.csv
```

I don't know how to use write.csv to return different files based on origin data frame name.

Comment: I edit data frame names  for different names

Comment: Do you have only these dataframes in the environment? Or there are other dataframes as well that you don't want to write?

Comment: I have other dataframes in the environment. But these dataframes already in a list since I read multiple cvs files at same time as a list. Also, I can only have these dataframes if needed.

Comment: `data` is that list with all the dataframes? What does `names(data)` return?

Comment: I edit the way to read csv files in main question. For names(data) , return  EU.csv  CHINA.csv   US.csv  Japan.csv  UK.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
path <- "D:/DATA/01/processdata/singlecity"
fileNames = list.files(path, pattern="*.csv$", full.names = TRUE)

lapply(seq_along(fileNames), function(x){
  file <- fileNames[x]
  data <- subset(read.csv(file), grepl('2002|2003|2004|2005|2006', V2))
  write.csv(data, sprintf('D:/DATA/01/processdata/singlecity/T1/%s_t%d.csv', 
            tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file)), x), row.names = FALSE)
})
```

Comment: How to deal with different data frame names, for example A, B ,C, how to export A_t.csv, B_t.csv, C_t.csv, also how to write into a new path

Comment: Thank you, it works, great!  Also, how to save these new files to a different path rather same path?  For example:new_path <- "D:/DATA/01/processdata/singlecity/T1"

Comment: You can add the path in `sprintf` directly. See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution modifying the `for` loop you've shared.

```r
dfs <- list(dataframe1, dataframe2, dataframe3)

for (i in seq_along(dfs)) {
   y <- data.table(dfs[[i]])
   y <- dplyr::filter(y, grepl('2002|2003|2004|2005|2006', V2))
   write.csv(y, paste0("datafram_t", i, ".csv"))
}
```

This will create files with the names you've requested:

```
datafram_t1.csv
datafram_t2.csv
datafram_t3.csv
```